# Oracle SQL queries - explain plan big estimated/actual row differences

Tags: sql, oracle11g, query-optimization, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

I have a problem which I'm finding hard to understand. I have two queries that are running slow. So I started to investigate the performance issues. All the tables in both queries have had there stats updated recently, so when I ran both queries using the /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ hint I was amazed when I viewed the actual stats using the below.

```
    select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'ALLSTATS LAST'));
```

There was a big difference between the estimated rows and actual rows to the explain plans. **What are the possible causes to this? Why the big difference if the table stats are up to date? I could start using hints but I'd rather let the optimizer.**

I have included the SQL querys and explain plans below.

```
select /*+ ORDERED USE_NL(prod,tle,uh,bro) gather_plan_statistics */  
      prod.cre_surr_id, 
      tle.title , 
      min(uh.performance_date)     performance_date, 
      prod.year_of_production, 
      prod.production_type  type_code 
from   wacsusers.prod_date_constraint_vw pdcv join prblk.productions  prod ON prod.cre_surr_id = pdcv.cre_surr_id 
   inner join titles tle on tle.cre_surr_id = prod.cre_surr_id and tle.tt_code = 'R' 
   left join prblk.usage_headers uh on uh.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id = prod.cre_surr_id 
   left join broadcasters bro on bro.tp_surr_id = uh.bro_broadcast_by_tp_surr_id 
 where  pdcv.title like 'BELIEVE%'  and uh.performance_date between to_date('01-JAN-1900','DD-MON-YYYY') and to_date('01-JAN-2900','DD-MON-YYYY')
  AND    prod.dn_prst_status = '4'  
  AND    prod.medium_type = 'AV' 
  group by prod.cre_surr_id, 
        prod.production_type, 
        tle.title, 
        prod.year_of_production, 
        prod.music_content_indicator 
HAVING   (prod.music_content_indicator IN ('Y', 'N') 
  OR prod.music_content_indicator IS NULL 
  OR (prod.music_content_indicator = 'W' 
  AND (prod.production_type = 'COM' 
  AND MIN (uh.performance_date) BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 1091) AND (SYSDATE - 90)) 
  OR (prod.production_type != 'COM' AND MIN (uh.performance_date) 
  BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 1091) AND (SYSDATE - 90)))) order by title asc
```

[image: Product search explain plan]

```
  1 - filter(("PROD"."MUSIC_CONTENT_INDICATOR"='Y' OR "PROD"."MUSIC_CONTENT_INDICATOR"='N' OR "PROD"."MUSIC_CONTENT_INDICATOR" IS NULL OR 
          ("PROD"."MUSIC_CONTENT_INDICATOR"='W' AND "PROD"."PRODUCTION_TYPE"='COM' AND MIN("UH"."PERFORMANCE_DATE")>=SYSDATE@!-1091 AND 
          MIN("UH"."PERFORMANCE_DATE")<=SYSDATE@!-90) OR ("PROD"."PRODUCTION_TYPE"<>'COM' AND MIN("UH"."PERFORMANCE_DATE")>=SYSDATE@!-1091 AND 
          MIN("UH"."PERFORMANCE_DATE")<=SYSDATE@!-90)))
   7 - filter(("PTM"."MUSIC_CONTENT_INDICATOR" IS NULL OR "PTM"."MUSIC_CONTENT_INDICATOR"="CONSTANTS"."CONTENT_YES"() OR 
          "PTM"."MUSIC_CONTENT_INDICATOR"="CONSTANTS"."CONTENT_NO"() OR ("PTM"."START_DTM">=SYSDATE@!-"CONSTANTS"."FLICS_INC_STA_DYS_AGO"() AND 
          "PTM"."START_DTM"<=SYSDATE@!-"CONSTANTS"."FLICS_INC_END_DYS_AGO"() AND "PTM"."PRODUCTION_TYPE"<>"CONSTANTS"."PROD_TYPE_COMMERCIAL"()) OR 
          ("PTM"."START_DTM">=SYSDATE@!-"CONSTANTS"."CLICS_INC_STA_DYS_AGO"() AND "PTM"."START_DTM"<=SYSDATE@!-"CONSTANTS"."CLICS_INC_END_DYS_AGO"() AND 
          "PTM"."PRODUCTION_TYPE"="CONSTANTS"."PROD_TYPE_COMMERCIAL"() AND "PTM"."MUSIC_CONTENT_INDICATOR"="CONSTANTS"."CONTENT_WAITING"())))
   8 - access("PTM"."TITLE" LIKE 'BELIEVE%')
   filter("PTM"."TITLE" LIKE 'BELIEVE%')
   9 - filter(("PROD"."DN_PRST_STATUS"='4' AND "PROD"."MEDIUM_TYPE"='AV'))
  10 - access("PROD"."CRE_SURR_ID"="PTM"."CRE_SURR_ID")
  12 - access("TLE"."CRE_SURR_ID"="PROD"."CRE_SURR_ID" AND "TLE"."TT_CODE"='R')
  13 - access("UH"."PROD_EXPLOITATION_CRE_SURR_ID"="PROD"."CRE_SURR_ID")
   filter("UH"."PROD_EXPLOITATION_CRE_SURR_ID" IS NOT NULL)
  14 - filter(("UH"."PERFORMANCE_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 1900-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "UH"."PERFORMANCE_DATE"<=TO_DATE(' 2900-01-01 
          00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')))
```

--

```
SELECT   /*+ gather_plan_statistics */  prod.cre_surr_id, 
       tle.title, prod.year_of_production, 
       prod.music_content_indicator 
 FROM     prblk.productions prod 
     INNER JOIN titles tle ON tle.cre_surr_id = prod.cre_surr_id AND tle.tt_code = 'R' 
        JOIN  (SELECT DISTINCT cc.prod_cre_surr_id 
               FROM   prblk.creation_components cc
               INNER JOIN works wrk  ON wrk.cre_surr_id = cc.wrk_cre_surr_id 
               WHERE  wrk.logically_deleted_y IS NULL 
               AND EXISTS   ( SELECT  1 
                           FROM   tle_title_tokens ttt  
                           WHERE token_type in ('E', 'N')  
                           AND dn_wrk_cre_surr_id = wrk.cre_surr_id  
                           AND  search_token LIKE :title||'%' )                                          
               AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1  
                           FROM   works_ips wips,  
                                ip_name_tokens ipnt  
                           WHERE  wips.ip_surr_id = ipnt.ip_surr_id  
                           AND    ipnt.search_token like :writer||'%'  
                           AND ipnt.token_type = 'N'  
                           AND wips.wrk_cre_surr_id = wrk.cre_surr_id)  
            AND cc.dn_ccst_status <> '6' ) cct ON cct.prod_cre_surr_id = prod.cre_surr_id  
            AND (( prod.music_content_indicator = 'W'  
            AND (SELECT MIN (uh.performance_date) 
                 FROM   prblk.usage_headers uh 
                 WHERE  uh.prod_exploitation_cre_surr_id = prod.cre_surr_id) BETWEEN SYSDATE -  CASE prod.production_type WHEN 'COM'                                                                                                         THEN 1091 
                                                                                                      ELSE 1091                                                                                                     END 
                   AND SYSDATE -  CASE prod.production_type WHEN 'COM' 
                                           THEN 90 
                                           ELSE 90 
                                END    ) OR NVL  (prod.music_content_indicator, 'N') in ('Y','N') ) ORDER BY title asc
```

[image: Work Search explain Plan]

```
 Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
 ---------------------------------------------------

  2 - filter((NVL("SYS_ALIAS_1"."MUSIC_CONTENT_INDICATOR",'N')='Y' OR NVL("SYS_ALIAS_1"."MUSIC_CONTENT_INDICATOR",'N')='N' OR 
          ("SYS_ALIAS_1"."MUSIC_CONTENT_INDICATOR"='W' AND >=SYSDATE@!-1091 AND <=SYSDATE@!-90)))
  5 - access("CCT"."PROD_CRE_SURR_ID"="SYS_ALIAS_1"."CRE_SURR_ID")
  8 - access("WRK"."CRE_SURR_ID"="CC"."WRK_CRE_SURR_ID")
  9 - access("TTT"."DN_WRK_CRE_SURR_ID"="WRK"."CRE_SURR_ID")
 10 - access("WIPS"."WRK_CRE_SURR_ID"="WRK"."CRE_SURR_ID")
 11 - filter("WRK"."LOGICALLY_DELETED_Y" IS NULL)
 12 - access("WIPS"."IP_SURR_ID"="IPNT"."IP_SURR_ID")
 13 - access("IPNT"."TOKEN_TYPE"='N' AND "IPNT"."SEARCH_TOKEN" LIKE :WRITER||'%')
   filter("IPNT"."SEARCH_TOKEN" LIKE :WRITER||'%')
 16 - access((("TTT"."TOKEN_TYPE"='E' OR "TTT"."TOKEN_TYPE"='N')) AND "TTT"."SEARCH_TOKEN" LIKE :TITLE||'%')
   filter("TTT"."SEARCH_TOKEN" LIKE :TITLE||'%')
 17 - filter(("CC"."WRK_CRE_SURR_ID" IS NOT NULL AND "CC"."DN_CCST_STATUS"<>'6'))
 19 - access("TLE"."CRE_SURR_ID"="SYS_ALIAS_1"."CRE_SURR_ID" AND "TLE"."TT_CODE"='R')
 23 - access("UH"."PROD_EXPLOITATION_CRE_SURR_ID"=:B1)
```

Comment: First, double check how many rows the optimizer thinks the table has via: select num_rows from dba_tables where table_name = "<TABLE_NAME>";. If they match or are reasonably close, then you most likely have data skew, which Tom Kyte delves into how to help the optimizer with this issue here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-nov/o64asktom-2298498.html

Comment: There are two issues with your explain plans: 1. there are incomplete, there is no "predicate information" part that is printed at the bottom of the plan. 2. They are bitmaps, and therefore very hard to read and analyse. Please generate plans again using commands: `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR query`, then `SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.Display)`, and copy them **as a text** (not bitmaps), and also **entire** plans, together with predicate information at the bottom.

Comment: I've added the  "predicate information" part to the explain plans